# Open file from firebase in web

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am developing a web app in flutter and I need to be able to view files that are in firebase cloud storage.
The problem is that it only lets me download the file and not view, how do I do that?

I tried doing this but it opens a new page and downloads the file

```
void _openFileInBrowser() async {
    const url = 'file_url';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Impossibile aprire il link $url';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the file url you can do as follows:

```
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
  link.setAttribute("target", "whatever_you_like");
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
```